# Pure virtual functions and multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, pure-virtual

I have a (guaranteed tree-shaped) cascade of classes like

```
class rock_bottom {
    ...
    virtual foo() = 0;
};

class A : rock_bottom {...}

class intermediate: rock_bottom {...}   

class B : intermediate {...}

class higher_up {...}

class C : higher_up {...}
```

I want to implement foo() in the lettered classes A, B, C. Where do I need to declare foo? (Virtual? Pure?) Do I need (trivial) implementations in the middle layers intermediate and higher_up?

Comment: If it's pure virtual, you are required to implement it in every non-abstract class which derives from `rock_bottom`. Otherwise, you must not.

Comment: You must implement with same signature (virtual is optional).

Comment: @Aleph: Not every class. Just the ones you want to be non-abstract (or base classes of those, direct or indirect).

Comment: @MikeSeymour You're right of course, forgive me for being imprecise.

Comment: Is `higher_up` supposed to derive from one of the other classes? As posted, `C` doesn't have anything to override.

Comment: Your question title mentions multiple-inheritance, but there is no multiple-inheritance in the example you have given.

Answer (score 2):

**Question:**

> I want to implement foo() in the lettered classes A, B, C. Where do I need to declare `foo`? (Virtual? Pure?)

**Answer:**

That question needs to be asked in reverse. In which base class does it make sense to create the interface `foo`. Let's take some classes that you might find in application.

```
struct Shape {};
struct Rectangle : public Shape {};
struct Square : public Rectangle {};
struct Ellipse : public Shape {};
struct Circle : public Ellipse {};
```

It makes sense that all `Shape` be able to return their area and perimeter. So you put them as `virtual` member functions in `Shape`.

```
struct Shape 
{
   virtual double area() const = 0;
   virtual double perimeter() const = 0;
};
```

Before you can create an instance of sub-type of `Shape`, you must implement them.

If you want to be able to create a `Rectangle`, those functions must be implemented in `Rectangle` since there are no other intermediate classes.

If you want to be able to create a `Square`, those functions must be implemented either in `Rectangle`, `Square`, or both.

Similarly, if you want to be able to create a `Ellipse`, those functions must be implemented in `Ellipse` since there are no other intermediate classes.

If you want to be able to create a `Circle`, those functions must be implemented either in `Ellipse`, `Circle`, or both.

However, only `Rectangle`s have length and width. Only `Ellipse`s have major radius and minor radius. It doesn't make sense to add virtual member functions in `Shape` to return those values.

**Question:**

> Do I need (trivial) implementations in the middle layers intermediate and higher_up?

**Answer:**

No, you don't. The answer to the previous question should clarify that more.

Answer (score 1):

Each override needs to be declared in the class that implements it; in your case, `A`, `B` and `C`, since you say each will provide an override.

There's no need to declare it in any intermediate class, assuming you're happy for them to remain abstract. They inherit the pure function from `rock_bottom`, and there's no point overriding that with another pure function.